# How do you link precompiled libraries in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, ninja

```
# file(COPY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glew32.lib DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/libs)
# file(COPY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libglfw3dll.a DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/libs)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
# libs/glew32.lib
# libs/libglfw3dll.a
# "main.cpp"
# )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
libs/glew32.lib
libs/libglfw3dll.a
)
```

I've tried doing every option here but they end up causing linking errors. I tried both compiling from src and using every available format glfw and glew provided.

Comment: Please show a [mre] including full error messages

Comment: I believe both of these libraries are supported by CMake and have finders already. You may want to use find_package() instead of this.

Comment: I did but emcmake breaks when you use find_package for some reason

Answer (score 4):

I usually create a CMake target first to import the prebuilt/precompiled library, then use `target_link_libraries` like y ou normally link to a CMake library target. The benefit is you can control the dependency being a PRIVATE dependency or a PUBLIC one.

```
project(YourCoolProject)

# Import a prebuilt library to a CMake target
add_library(Foo SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(Foo PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG   "/absolute-path/to/prebuilt-debug-library"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "/absolute-path/to/prebuilt-release-library"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELWITHDEBINFO "/absolute-path/to/prebuilt-relwithdebinfo-library"
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "/absolute-path/to/include-dir"
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Foo)
```

Notes:

1. The choice of `IMPORTED_LOCATION_<CONFIG>` depends on the build type you provide to CMake (`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=<CONFIG> ...`).
2. In order to replace the absolute path, you can use `find_library` to utilize CMake to find your library and store it in a variable and use `find_path` to find the include directory.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `target_link_directories()` as well to tell the compiler where to find the libraries:

```
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/)
```